# Class in generic and as literal in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In Java we can do the following:

```
Map<Class<?>, Integer> countsByClass;
...
countsByClass.put(String.class, 1);
```

How to do the same in TypeScript (or something like it)?

```
let countsByClass: Map<???, Number>;
...
countsByClass.put(???, 1);
```

Comment: Don’t you just mean generic class? Like Map<T, U>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
class Foo {}

let countsByClass: Map<new (...args: any[]) => any, number> = new Map();
countsByClass.set(Foo, 5);

console.log(countsByClass.get(Foo));
```

Can also define an intermediate `Class` type:

```
type Class<T = any> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
```

and then the `Map` declaration becomes cleaner:

```
let countsByClass: Map<Class, number> = new Map();
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1sdnsb?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33224545/4638529) to a similar question for more info on why `new (...args: any[]) => any` works

Comment: Could you explain this `new (...args: any[]) => any`?

Comment: @Pavel_K Here's a [blog post](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/05/26/typescript-2-2-mixin-classes) explaining it. One interesting part being `The type Constructor<T> is an alias for the construct signature that describes a type which can construct objects of the generic type T and whose constructor function accepts an arbitrary number of parameters of any type.` (`Constructor` is the equivalent of `Class` in my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean giving a generic type for a class. Ofcourse you can provide multiple types if you need those.

Example:

```
class Map<T, U> { }
```

Correct me if I’m wrong.