# How to ensure that argument type of Class implements an interface

Tags: typescript

I have a class that implements interface `IField`

```
export class FieldImplementation implements IField { };
```

And a service that stores types:

```
import { FieldImplementation } from '../component';
...
service.addField(FieldImplementation);
```

I need to ensure that the argument passed to `addField` implements `IField`.

Currently `addField` looks like this:

```
addField(field: any) {
...
}
```

Comment: you want the argument to be a class constructor that makes `IField` objects?  That would be `addField(field: new(...args: any[])=>IField)`.  Do you have a restriction on the number of arguments to that constructor?

Comment: "I can still pass other classes that do not implement IField".  Show us, please.  I think either `IField` is empty (and this is a question about [structural typing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) in disguise) or something else is going on.  Either way we need to see more code I think.

Comment: "Only one argument can be passed" an argument of what type?  In case it's not clear, I'm asking about the argument(s) to the `constructor()` inside any `class` that `implements IField`.

Comment: @jcalz actually I'm sorry. It does work. If you create an answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the constructor signature, also known as [a "newable" type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224047/how-to-specify-any-newable-type-in-typescript?rq=1).  You want the parameter to `addField()` to be something you call `new` on to get an `IFIeld`.  That is representable like this:

```
addField(field: new(...args: any[])=>IField) {
  // ...
  new field(/* some kind of arguments */);
}
```

That signature will accept any constructor producing an `IField`, but there could be a mismatch with the arguments that constructor accepts.

---

If you are expecting `field` to be called with `new` and a particular number and type of arguments, you can express that too.  For example, if you want `field` to be a no-arg constructor:

```
addField(field: new()=>IField) {
  // ...
  new field(); // no arguments
}
```

Then, if `FieldImplementation` is a class with a no-arg constructor, it will succeed:

```
service.addField(FieldImplementation); // okay
```

whereas a class that requires a constructor parameter will fail, which is good:

```
class NeedAString implements IField { 
  constructor(private myString: string) { }
};
service.addField(NeedAString); // error, NeedAString is not a no-arg constructor
// error is desirable because you don't want addField() implementation
// to call new NeedAString();
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!